# Update user in OneLogin using SCIM

Tags: onelogin, scim

I am trying to implement SCIM Integration with OneLogin. Create, Delete works fine, but on updating a user, my server sends a 200 OK response, still OneLogin server provides me an error without any further description.

Its an "INTERNAL PROVISIONING ERROR"

How to check whats wrong within the scim application with only this detail?

Answer (score 0):

Reach out to developer support at OneLogin (scim-support@onelogin.com). At the end of the day, you're probably sending badly formatted JSON which causes the parser on their end to barf.

One item I've noticed recently is that folks are including // comments in their JSON and that's No Bueno (at least for OneLogin's parsers)